# Border around legend item in highcharts

Tags: css, highcharts

I know there are ways to draw borders around the entire legend in Highcharts. How to draw a border around each legend item in Highcharts 5.0?

[image]

Comment: Don't know anything about Highcharts, but maybe....border-radius ?

Comment: border radius is for the entire legend. not specific legend item.

Answer (score 2):

This seems trickier than I first thought. One thing that I think is a potential solution is adding `useHTML: true` to the `legend` and then styling using CSS and Pseudo-elements.

With `useHTML` you could then style it using CSS like this:

```
.highcharts-legend-item {
padding: 1em;
}

.highcharts-legend-item > span {
position: relative;
overflow: visible!important;
}

.highcharts-legend-item > span:after {
content: "";
position: absolute;
width: 110%;
border: 2px solid #ddd;
padding: 1em 1em 0.5em;
top: -2px;
left: -25px;
border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Please see this [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/53epvjgf/3/) for an example.

I'm sure you'll need to adjust the styling but it should be a start.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Excellent! The JS Fiddle is really helpful to show it works before I try it out.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. Highcharts has a piece of documentation titled [Style by CSS](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/style-by-css) which details how to do this.

By the look if it, you'll want to do something like:

```css
.highcharts-legend-item {
  border: 1px solid tomato;
}
```

Comment: tried. doesn't work. can u show a js fiddle where u might have this working?